# Updating List In Dictionary Adds To List in Every Key Python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop, append

So the below code, kind of rough, but I have been trying to debug this for a while.

So in essence lolbinsbehaviouralshellcommands is a dict of lists, with a number of keys prepopulated.

The code iterates through, and when it finds a match, it should append that value to the list inside the dictionary inside the list located at lolbinsbehaviouralshellcommands[behaviourshellcommandlolbin]

What actually happens is that it updates all lists for all keys within the dictionary, I can't for the life of me work out why. Please tell me how to update  just the  lolbinsbehaviouralshellcommands[behaviourshellcommandlolbin] list within the lolbinsbehaviouralshellcommands dictionary of lists.

```
    lolbinsbehaviouralshellcommandsclone = copy.deepcopy(lolbinsbehaviouralshellcommands)
                    for behaviourshellcommandlolbin in lolbinsbehaviouralshellcommandsclone:

                        #print(key)
                        #print("doggo")
                        if behaviourshellcommandlolbin in lowercaserawshell:
                            print("it's a match")
                            print(behaviourshellcommandlolbin)
                            print(lowercaserawshell)
                            #exit()
                            #if rawshell not in lolbinsbehaviouralshellcommands[behaviourshellcommandlolbin]:
                            print(type(lolbinsbehaviouralshellcommands[behaviourshellcommandlolbin]))
                            print(len(lolbinsbehaviouralshellcommands[behaviourshellcommandlolbin]))
                            #exit()
                            if len(lolbinsbehaviouralshellcommands[behaviourshellcommandlolbin]) == 0:
                                print(lolbinsbehaviouralshellcommands[behaviourshellcommandlolbin])
                                print(lolbinsbehaviouralshellcommands)

    #                           exit()
                                lolbinsbehaviouralshellcommands[behaviourshellcommandlolbin].append(str(rawshell))
                                print(lolbinsbehaviouralshellcommands)
                                print(behaviourshellcommandlolbin)
                                exit()
```

Comment: did you try `extend`?

Comment: still adds it to every element of dictionary, just splits it like this if i use extend: : ['(', 'o', 'p', 'e', 'n', ')', ' ', 'c', 'm', 'd', '.', 'e', 'x', 'e', '/', 'c', ' ', 'p', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', '1', '2', '7', '.', '0', '.', '0', '.', '1', ' ', '&', ' ', 'd', 'e', 'l', ' ', '/', 'q', ' ', 'C', ':', '\\', '5', '5', '4', '8', 'd', '5', '9', '1', '6', '4', '6', '1', '9', 'c', 'f', '9', '3', 'f', '6', '0', '0', '4',)', ']'],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was how i instantiated the dictionary of lists.

If you create a list the first way then it means all keys are referencing a single list.

```
lolbaslistdict = dict.fromkeys(lowercaselolbas, [])
```

The second way creates a seperate list for each dictionary key.

```
lolbaslistdict = {k: [] for k in lowercaselolbas}
```